# Change apache mpm from event to prefork

Tags: apache2

I recently installed Apache/2.4.6 from source. At present the MPM module enabled is  mpm_event_module. I want to enable the prefork mpm, but not sure from where to do that.
I am aware of changing the mpm module from /etc/sysconfig/httpd in case of the apache installed using yum. But in my case as the installinon is from source, I could not not do the same.
I tried recompiling apche using   './configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-module=prefork' , but the mpm is still mpm_event_module. Clearly the issue is with defining prefork as the mpm.

I could also see that the installation directory has the prefork.c module. There must be a way to define it as the mpm.

Could someone please help.

Comment: put it on http://serverfault.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

In versions prior to 2.4, you cannot change the MPM of the binary Apache2 installation at run-time.

You have to compile Apache with the desired MPM using the `--with-mpm=MODULE NAME` command line option to the config script. To change MPM, the binary must be rebuilt.

You can determine which MPM Apache2 is currently built with by executing `apache2 -l` or `httpd -l` on the command line.

Brief but very clear documentation on this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mpm.html

In version 2.4, you can also build MPMs as dynamic modules which allows changing the MPM at run-time.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html#dynamic

Comment: Thanks Marcell. I recompiled Apache prefork using the e --with-mpm=MODULE NAME command. Earlier I was trying the same using  --enable-module=prefork.

Went through those links. Reaffirms the fact that every thing is out there. You just need to look properly.:)

Comment: You are welcome. Depending whether you chose the MPM(s) to be dynamic or static modules, you'll be able to change the current MPM in different ways but that should be straight forward now following the document from the answer.